# Remove border from ion-button

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, button

I am building an Ionic App. I have rounded the buttons in order to make them more beautiful, but when I do that the border stays just like the photo that is linked.
I have tried with these different methods but none of them worked:

```
border: 0px !important;
border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
background-image: none !important;
border-bottom: none !important;
text-shadow: none !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
```

[button 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWrZV.png)

It also happens with this other button:
[button 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vycs1.png)

I cannot use ion-buttons because the text just crashes with it.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: That is looks like `box-shadow`, isn't that? May be you can try `box-shadow: none !important` for that

Comment: --box-shadow works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use the css properties **--border-color** and **--border-width** like this: `--border-color: none; --border-width: 0px !important;`. I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties of the ion-button:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button

```
--border-color  Border color of the button
--border-radius Border radius of the button
--border-style  Border style of the button
--border-width  Border width of the button
--box-shadow    Box shadow of the button
```

these can be applied to the specific class.

Or within the global.scss file, just add your styling:

```
ion-button {
...
}
```